# Why cannot author edit pages?

Tags: capabilities

I have this in my `functions.php` (child theme)

```
//Add capabilities to author, so he/she can edit...    
 function add_theme_caps() {
    // gets the author role
    $role = get_role( 'author' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_pages' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_pages' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_posts' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_posts' );  
    $role->add_cap( 'publish_posts' );  
    $role->add_cap( 'publish_pages' );  
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_posts' );   
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_pages' );       
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');
```

but when I log in as an author the author is not able to edit pages (that admin has created) **why?** It's possible for the logged in author to view the pages, but not to edit and save anything.

Comment: Why not making the author an editor instead?

Comment: @cablop - I seriously don't remember :_)

Answer (score 1):

It was a simple thing when thinking of it... I needed to add:

```
$role->add_cap( 'edit_others_pages ' );
```